# How to link Access with MySQL, but not exclusively

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

My organization has an extremely extensive Access front end that produces elaborate reports and analysis; lots and lots of logic embedded in modules, macros, forms, dynamically generated tables, queries (temporary and otherwise), etc.

So, fully abandoning the front end or rewriting as Win32 isn't really a solution.

At the same time, migrating 100% to MySQL backend isn't fully an option either, as we need to have access to the backend without the internet.  (Lots of analysis done on planes, airports, hotels with spotty internet, etc.)

What I'm looking for, is a way to do work locally in both the .accdb front end and back end, making small tweaks to data, and then push/commit the changes to MySQL for use in our client facing web app.

Is there a way to do that with ODBC / similar connections?

Comment: Yes you can. The exact details depend on how often you want to update and how you can keep track of where the last update left off but you can dynamically link the MySQL/ODBC tables to access with names slightly different than their corresponding access tables and update (or wipe/copy if overnight update is good enough) then de-link. On the other hand you can link all your access tables to another access file, put that on ODBC and link that to your web app bypassing MySQL altogether so you have live data.

Comment: Ah makes sense.  I hadn't thought of such a simple and 'dirty' workaround, but this sounds like a very effective and easy  solution.  Thanks much.